# WebChannel is deencoding parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, escaping, uri

I'm creating a WCF REST client. I need to pass an encrypted password by url string.
Sometimes the password contains characters like / because of the encryptation algorithm. I'm using Uri.EscapeDataString to escape the / characters, but when I call the method I need in the data contract the channel turn back the original string with de special characters that I need to escape.

**Here is my code.**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RegistroUsuario/NRO_POLIZA={NRO_POLIZA}&NRO_ORDEN={NRO_ORDEN}&COD_COLECTIVO={COD_COLECTIVO}&FEC_NACIMIENTO=&ROL={ROL}&USUARIO={USUARIO}&PASSWORD={PASSWORD}&EMAIL={EMAIL}&TIP_NIF=&COD_NIF=&TFN_MOVIL={TFN_MOVIL}&ID_PREGUNTA={ID_PREGUNTA}&RESPUESTA={RESPUESTA}&ORIGEN={ORIGEN}")]
RESPUESTA RegistroUsuarioConTarjeta(string NRO_POLIZA, string NRO_ORDEN, string COD_COLECTIVO, string ROL, String USUARIO, String PASSWORD, String EMAIL, String TFN_MOVIL, String ID_PREGUNTA, String RESPUESTA, String ORIGEN);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "RegistroUsuario/NRO_POLIZA=&NRO_ORDEN=&COD_COLECTIVO=&FEC_NACIMIENTO={FEC_NACIMIENTO}&ROL={ROL}&USUARIO={USUARIO}&PASSWORD={PASSWORD}&EMAIL={EMAIL}&TIP_NIF={TIP_NIF}&COD_NIF={COD_NIF}&TFN_MOVIL={TFN_MOVIL}&ID_PREGUNTA={ID_PREGUNTA}&RESPUESTA={RESPUESTA}&ORIGEN={ORIGEN}")]
RESPUESTA RegistroUsuarioSinTarjeta(string FEC_NACIMIENTO, string ROL, String USUARIO, String PASSWORD, String EMAIL, String TIP_NIF, String COD_NIF, String TFN_MOVIL, String ID_PREGUNTA, String RESPUESTA, String ORIGEN);


public static RESPUESTA RegistrarUsuario(RegistroAsegurado reg, int idEntorno, out String mensaje, LogServicio traza)
{
Uri baseAddress = new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.URL_WSAsegurados);
RESPUESTA resp = new RESPUESTA();            
mensaje = Recursos.Mensajes.MSG_009;

try
{
    //original password gB7Xs/ah3Y0uSv2IuDo/FBoVcsw=
    //Escaped password  gB7Xs%2Fah3Y0uSv2IuDo%2FFBoVcsw%3D**

    String urlPass = Uri.EscapeDataString(reg.Password);
    String urlEmail = Uri.EscapeDataString(reg.Email);
    String urlRespuestaPreg = Uri.EscapeDataString(reg.Respuesta_Pregunta);

    using (WebChannelFactory<IService> cf = new WebChannelFactory<IService>(baseAddress))
    { 
        IService channel = cf.CreateChannel();


        if(reg.TieneTarjeta)
        {                                      
            resp = channel.RegistroUsuarioConTarjeta(reg.NRO_POLIZA, reg.NRO_ORDEN, reg.COD_COLECTIVO, "A", reg.LoginName, urlPass, urlEmail, reg.TlfMovil, reg.Id_Pregunta.ToString(), urlRespuestaPreg, idEntorno.ToString());
        }
        else
        {               
            resp = channel.RegistroUsuarioSinTarjeta(reg.Fecha_Nacimiento.ToString(formatoFecha), "A", reg.LoginName, urlPass, urlEmail, reg.Tipo_Documento, reg.Numero_Documento, reg.TlfMovil, reg.Id_Pregunta.ToString(), urlRespuestaPreg, idEntorno.ToString());
        }

        traza.InsertaMensaje(resp.ToString());
    }
}
catch (CommunicationException ex)
{
    traza.InsertaException(ex);
    mensaje = ex.Message;
    resp = null;  
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    traza.InsertaException(ex);
    mensaje = ex.Message;
    resp = null;
}


return resp;
```

}

**An thats the Exception I'm having**  As you can see the password is not escaped ¿Why?

```
There was no endpoint lintening at
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx/servicios/RegistroUsuario/NRO_POLIZA=000000000&NRO_ORDEN=1&COD_COLECTIVO=0000&FEC_NACIMIENTO=&ROL=A&USUARIO=utrisNNNN&PASSWORD=gB7Xs/ah3Y0uSv2IuDo/FBoVcsw%3D&EMAIL=supermario%40supermario.com&TIP_NIF=&COD_NIF=&TFN_MOVIL=666666666&ID_PREGUNTA=1&RESPUESTA=Dba3Sv9pJ6y9C/ugXGYCzFJdxUA%3D&ORIGEN=200
```

The same problems is apearing with the "Respuesta_Pregunta" parameter but not with de email parameter.

I don't understand that, and I don't kwon how to solve it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of your `UriTemplate`'s format. The way you have it,

```
UriTemplate = "RegistroUsuario/NRO_POLIZA={NRO_POLIZA}&..."
```

The values are considered part of the URL's path and not the URL's query string (no question mark). If you would change it to include a question mark, the values would be considered to be part of the query string, and would be handled correctly:

```
UriTemplate = "RegistroUsuario?NRO_POLIZA={NRO_POLIZA}&..."
```

Or even:

```
UriTemplate = "RegistroUsuario/?NRO_POLIZA={NRO_POLIZA}&..."
```

Comment: Thanks, that's works fine. But now the problem is that the web service is implemented using Talend, and we don't know the way to put '?' in the Uri. Talend throws an exception